# is it possible to inherit using in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance, c#-4.0

i have a Project that has Solution and Class Library 
i made a BaseClass Called **ManagerClass.cs** that inherits from **System.Web.UI.Page** to make this class my BaseClass for Every thing, well in Class Library i have a class called **AlertMessage.cs** i want to use this class directly from any inherited class as example:
This Is My Default Class Inherited from Manager Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomModalMessages
{
    public partial class Default : ManagerClass
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnPopUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AlertMessage.Show("", false, Page, GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

Also My Manager Class Looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SharedComponent;

namespace CustomModalMessages
{
    public class ManagerClass : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            AlertMessage.Show("", true, Page, GetType());

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        protected override void OnError(EventArgs args)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException(); 

            string sStackTrace = ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            string sErrorDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            string sErrorPage = ex.Source.ToString();
            string sErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see i made a Using SharedComponent; i want this using to public in all inherited classes without Calling the Using.

My Hierarchy looks like this:
 [image: Solution Explorer Hierarchy]

Thanks in advance

Comment: No that's not possible ... only in aspx pages it's possible ... By specifying in web.config .. it is possible to include a assembly namespace for all .aspx pages .. but you don't have the facility for aspx.cs pages ...

Comment: If you do not want to include `using SharedComponent;`, you are required to type `SharedComponent.AlertMessage.Show(...);`. You cannot totally avoid it inside code behind.

Comment: i may move this class to my current Project instead of Class Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using` statements cannot be inherited in C#. They don't even compile to code - they're just a utility for the developer so that he doesn't have to type the fully qualified type name (e.g. `SharedComponent.AlertMessage`)

Using [Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:%3Eil/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5kNIpgDcA9mAAmMALIAKAJSt2nAL555QA==) you can see that this class:

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

is compiled to

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 13 (0xd)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldstr ""
        IL_0006: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_000b: nop
        IL_000c: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x205e
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

The line with `IL_0006` inside method `M` is the point of interest here. A fully qualified type name is specified in the IL code and the `using` statement is nowhere to be found.

Comment: if i got you right, your answer is : there is no way inherit a Using.